# How to use a 1x1 white pixel as an indirect light (Google Filament)

Tags: android, kotlin, 3d, google-filament

I am trying to create a simple solid color skybox with a solid color indirect light. I understand that the lighting will look flat but it's ok for my use case.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
val oneWhitePixel =
    ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArrayOf(0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte()))

val whitePixelBuffer = Texture.PixelBufferDescriptor(
    oneWhitePixel,
    Texture.Format.RGB,
    Texture.Type.UBYTE
)

val indirectLightCube = Texture.Builder()
    .width(1)
    .height(1)
    .sampler(Texture.Sampler.SAMPLER_CUBEMAP)
    .format(Texture.InternalFormat.RGB8)
    .build(engine)
    .also { texture ->
        texture.setImage(engine, 0, whitePixelBuffer)
    }

val indirectLight = IndirectLight.Builder()
    .reflections(indirectLightCube)
    .build(engine)
```

However, this results in only the top (+Y) and right face (+X) being lit while the rest of the cube remains black as shown below.

[image: Cube]

I have also looked at [this discussion](https://github.com/google/filament/discussions/3495) in the Filament repo and tried using FaceOffsets in the setImage() method but I couldn't get it to work without throwing a BufferOverflowException

This is my attempt at using FaceOffsets:

```
val faceOffsets = IntArray(6)
faceOffsets[0] = 0
faceOffsets[1] = 1
faceOffsets[2] = 2
faceOffsets[3] = 3
faceOffsets[4] = 4
faceOffsets[5] = 5

texture.setImage(engine, 0, whitePixelBuffer, faceOffsets)   // This method seems to be deprecated for java as well
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to implement this?

Thank you in advance!